# Flexbox variable height children in React Native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm new to Flexbox, Exponent, and React Native, so I'm not certain if I'm doing this correctly. Any help you can provide would be appreciated and I've provided a snack below that could be used as a starting point.

My screen has a header that's 40px tall at the top and a tab bar that's 40px tall on the bottom.

Between them, I'd like to have a full-width, full-height column that has rows of content with charts on the left, and a header (Billing, Budget, Labor) to the right of the chart with variable number of rows of data beneath the header. These rows have a key that's left-aligned (Invoiced, Not Invoiced, Total, etc.) and a value that's right-aligned (500.00, 250.00, 750.00, etc.).

Because the number of rows of data vary (3, 4, 3, etc.), I don't want to hard-code the heights of each chart row. I also don't want these rows to stretch/grow to the height of the center column, but allow for whitespace beneath them).

How can I build this so that:
1. Rows don't fill the height of the center column, but align on the top and leave whitespace below.
2. Charts are left-aligned next to their data.
3. Data figures/values (e.g., 500.00) are right aligned next to their keys (e.g., Invoiced).

[image: Designed example of the above]
[image: Rough concept of the example above]

Any help would be amazing. If you could provide a snack.expo.io, that'd be even better! Here's a rough example of what I mean, but you can see that the rows are stretching to the height (so there's a lot of wasted space and no empty space at the bottom) and the key/values in the data aren't justified so the key is on the left and the value is right-aligned. 
https://snack.expo.io/HknEsZ5uz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated a few lines, does this look better? https://snack.expo.io/S1cF5bsdG

`flex: 1` allows a view to fill all space available, so if you have two views on the same level of a hierarchy with `flex: 1`, both views split all vertical space equally. Read more: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flex

Comment: This is phenomenal and exactly what I needed to learn. I was so confused why it showed fine in HTML/CSS, but didn't display the same in RN. Thank you so much!